# Display of bivariant data with a magnitude and intensity

Tags: qgis, heat-map

I am trying to produce a heat map display.
I am wanting to display two dependent data sets (flow rate & gas % at a well point) as a single heat map. The zone of influence is a 20m radius scaled to map point. I would like flow rate to display as a weighted size relative to the maximum zone of influence, and the methane content as the colour intensity of the attribute. Can anyone point me to the correct article?
I am using QGIS 3.28.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works